# Implementing recently introduced Android design and UI guidelines on 2.x versions

Tags: android, user-interface

Considering [Android Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html) announcement what is the best way to make apps which are compliant with them on Android 2.x phones? E.g. what is the best way to implement the ActionBar pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to use the [compatibilty libraries](http://developer.android.com/sdk/compatibility-library.html) directly, instead of another library based on those. Additionally, refer to the [Google I/O App](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) as stated at the bottom of the first link I gave. You can find the best practices about implementing a UI for several devices with compatibility libraries.

Comment: I'd be sincerely interested in hearing your thoughts on why you think it is better. I operated on the logic that ABS IS the compatibility libraries plus some extra code to help render an actionbar therefore achieving a good balance.

Comment: In my opinion, it's always better to decrease the dependencies. If I use the ABS I will depend not only the developers of ABS but also the Android developers. I would choose only to depend on the Android developers. In the future, if ABS decides not the support some of the features that the compatibility libraries does it would be bad for me to migrate my code. 

Also, I cannot see anything that ABS can do and normal ActionBar can't. I appreciate the efforts for ABS this is just my humble opinion to use the ActionBar directly.

Comment: That is a good point BUT ABS solves the problem that the actionbar is not available on pre 3.0 devices therefore you can't use it directly. This question revolves around version 2.X devices so this point is quite important.

Comment: My point is you can use Actionbar without ABS check this pattern for pre-11 Android devices: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

Answer (score 2):

[ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/download.html) is a starting point. It includes the compatibility libraries from Google and comes provided as a project rather than  JAR offering greater flexibility, should you need to alter anything. Version 4 is on the way which will also include ICS stuff.

As far as I am aware I believe ABS is backward compatible to 1.6, and makes use of the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. It uses an extended version of the holo theme to create a light and dark version that includes the extra ActionBar goodness, which in turn you can extend to style your app.

I recorded a tutorial on [YouTube to get people started.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=avcp6eD_X2k)

Comment: @user1234567 sorry did not see your response as I was on my smartphone and the above took a while to write.

Answer (score 1):

I found [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) to be pretty good. It will emulate ActionBar on older devices and use the native one on modern ones. It's an extension to Android compatibility library - so you will also get fragments and other ICS stuff.